# tensorflow.gradients gives None value

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, gradient

`model` is my trained Keras residual model. I'm trying to calculate the gradient of the loss w.r.t an input tensor, however:

```
tf.gradients(mse(model.predict(x), y), x[0])
```

(gradient of loss w.r.t an input tensor), gives me:

```
[None].
```

What does `None` here mean and how can I compute these gradients?

Comment: It means there is no gradient, to get gradients you need to fully use TensorFlow symbolic operations for it to work (so no model.predict).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute the gradient you must use symbolic tensors and operations:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.losses import the_loss_function   # import the suitable loss function

y = Input(shape=labels_shape)

# this is the gradient of loss with respect to inputs given some input data
grads = K.gradients(the_loss_function(y, model.output), model.inputs)
func = K.function(model.inputs + [y, K.learning_phase()], grads)

# usage in test mode = 0
out = func([input_data_array, input_labels_array, 0])

# usage in train mode = 1
out = func([input_data_array, input_labels_array, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, when I do so I get an `InvalidArgumentError`: `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'major_bn/keras_learning_phase' with dtype bool
  [[node major_bn/keras_learning_phase (defined at /home/ayush99/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:120)  = Placeholder[dtype=DT_BOOL, shape=<unknown>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]`

Comment: @AyushShridhar Use `K.learning_phase()` in the definition of function and pass a value to it when using the function. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm actually trying to implement the FGSM attack on my neural network. However I tried the above approach for implementing the attack, but I wasn't successful in fooling the network. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: @AyushShridhar Honestly, no. I have not worked with that attack. You can ask a new question and include your code (the relevant parts) and then people more familiar with this topic would be able to help.